# Google Maps searching issue with placemarks

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geocoding

I'm developing a web page with a Google Maps application and I'm having a little trouble with something. As it stands, the web page has a functional map (without any layers) and a search bar. I'm new to programming so hopefully there is a quick fix that I'm missing.
When I search an address, there is a placemark that is placed on the map. However, the map doesn't zoom into the placemark. How can I make the map zoom in for each searched address?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map; 
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (55.1667, -114.4000);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        }
    function codeAddress () {
        var address = document.getElementById ("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)  {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
            map.setCenter(results [0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results [0].geometry.location
            });
            } 
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
    }); 
                            }
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call two functions:

(1) center the map on the marker

Either you already have the LatLng, or obtain it from `marker.getPosition()`, with it call `map.setCenter(myLatLng)`.

(2) Set the zoom of the map

`map.setZoom(zoomLevel)`, could be fixed around 12 to 16, or variable depending what kind of marker it is (street address or city overview?) This information can be stored in the marker variable, `marker.zoomLevel`.

```
function codeAddress () { 
  var address = document.getElementById ("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode ( {'address': address}, function(results, status) { 
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, 
        position: results[0].geometry.location });
      map.setZoom(16);
    } 
    else { 
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I need a little more guidance. If I wanted to set the map to zoom in 8 when I searched an address for example, how would the code look explicitly? and where in my code does this go?

Comment: Here's my script for the map, sorry it's not completely organized, i tried to make it better. The next comment contains the rest of it. 
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map; 
      function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder ();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (55.1667, 
   -114.4000);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById
  ("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
   }

Comment: function codeAddress () {
   var address = document.getElementById 
    ("address").value;
   geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': 
    address}, function(results,            status)  {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)           {
    map.setCenter(             results [0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker          ({
     map: map, 
     position: results            [0].geometry.location
    });
    } 
   else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful           for the following          reason: " + status);
     }
   }); 
   }
    </script>

Comment: is there a better way to post code on here so that it's easier to read?

Comment: Edit your question, paste your code, highlight it and click on the `{ }` icon

Comment: @user1422330 I updated my answer. It didn't seem to matter much where the setZoom was placed.

Comment: Thank you Heiter, it works. I really appreciate your clarity and patience